# Как в массив добавить переменную?

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть массив

```
$data = '[{"id": "$phone", "name": "$name", "phone": "$phone"}]';

$name = "test1";

$phone = "77777777777";
```

Как мне добавить в него переменные?
Важно чтобы массив был [{...}], иначе скрипт не работает

Comment: здесь нет ни одного массива. Массивы в РНР пишутся совсем по-другому

Comment: для того, чтобы из массива получить  "[{...}]" используется функция json_encode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$name = 'alex';
$data = ['ivan', $name];
```

Так добавляются переменные в массив в php
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php
Переменная это просто место в памяти, вписываешь название в массив и все. То как пишутся массивы в php пример выше